# Direct product of a family of groups/modules is the direct limit of a directed system formed by the family of groups/modules?

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, limits-colimits

Can the direct product of a family of groups/modules be regarded as the direct limit of a directed system? If yes, than can someone elaborate the desired directed system with it's objects and maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inverse limit. Let $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of $R$-modules. The ordered set $(I,=)$ with is right directed and it induces a natural inverse system $\{M_i,1_{M_i}\}_{i\in I}$ which inverse limit $\varprojlim M_i$ is trivially isomorphic to $\prod_{i\in I} M_i$ (both satisfies the same universal property).

Comment: What about the weak direct product? Can we say that the weak direct product is the direct limit of finite direct products?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the weak direct product.

Comment: I mean the subset of the product $∏_i\in _I M_i$ consisting of those $(x_i)$  for which $x_i =0$ for all but finitely many $i$.

Comment: You mean the direct sum, right? If yes, it is a direct limit. Just consider same ordered set and natural direct system. Also by universal property is trivial to see that they are isomorphic.